# Best way to clear cache of layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have editable layouts in my application.
It is not a good way to reset application, after each change of layouts
by touch tmp/restart.txt

Could someone propose other way to reset cache of layouts? Or better to
reset layout that exactly changed.

Thanks, Ildar

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for something like

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

Comment: no, I mean from application, then it working in production env.

Comment: I use it for production